# Matlab: error al calcular minimo de una funcion con fminbnd

Tags: matlab

soy un novato en Matlab, en mi primera relacion de ejercicios me piden calcular el minimo de una funcion dentro de un intervlalo especifico, tras pasar los parametros a la funcion fminbnd me da el siguiente fallo.

```
Undefined function or variable 'x'.

Error in Scriptfmin3 (line 1)
f=x^3-2*x-5

Error in run (line 63)
evalin('caller', [script ';']);
```

Mi script es el siguiente.

```
f=x^3-2*x-5
fminbnd(f,0,2)
```

Que estoy haciendo mal

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Te falta poner @(x):

```
f= @(x)x^3-2*x-5;
fminbnd(f,0,2)
```

Comment: Hola @migu3l705, aunque esta publicación puede servir para solucionar el problema de la pregunta, la respuesta en sí no se ajusta bien el formato del sitio. Le hace falta más información: ¿qué es lo que hace `@(x)`?¿por qué soluciona el problema? ¿puedes incluir alguna referencia? Lee sobre [answer] y completa el [tour] para más información. Un saludo.